# How to remove trailing whitespace *from selection* in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, whitespace, removing-whitespace

The question is as simple as stated in the title - how to remove the whitespace in Eclipse, but only from the selected lines.

There are a lot of answers on SO how to remove trailing whitespace in Eclipse. Most of them focus on automatically removing it on save and all of them concern removing **all** of the trailing whitespace in the file.
I want none of these, as I am working on large JS files that are awfully formatted and very frequently committed; removing all the trailing whitespaces in the file would easily cause merge conflicts and a lot of noise from the people.

So I want to select specific parts of the files and fix them, in the way that this is possible with Source -> Format (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>).

Comment: You can use Eclipse EASE (https://eclipse.org/ease/) to achieve this, I'll try and write a full answer later if I have time, but for inspiration you can see https://git.eclipse.org/c/ease/org.eclipse.ease.scripts.git/tree/JavaScript%20Snippets/comment_out_selection.js

Answer (score 0):

Shift-Ctrl-Right arrow will highlight whitespace to the right until next non-whitespace character (which may be newline). Press delete.  If you lose the newline, simply press enter.